# Return Json from Php to Swift Alamofire

Tags: php, json, swift, alamofire

Hi guys i am using alamofire on a swift 3 iphone program, my problem is that i need to return a value from the php page my problem is that the value that comes back to me is this. How do I make sure that the value I return is: no prova@email.it

I hope I have explained

**RETURN VALUE(NOT CORRECT):**

```
SUCCESS: {
message = "no Optional(\"prova@email.it\")";
```

}
no Optional("prova@email.it")

**SWIFT CODE:**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class User{

    //URL to our web service

    var email=""
    var password=""

    func PrintValue(){

       // print(username);
        //print(password);
    }

    func Login() -> String{

         //var ris="";
        var readvalue=""
        let URLString = "http://localhost/test/login_mobile.php"
        let parameters_value: Parameters = [
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        ]


        //Sending http post request
        Alamofire.request(URLString, method: .post, parameters: parameters_value).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting the json value from the server
                if let result = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    //displaying the message in label
                    readvalue = (jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?)!

                    print(readvalue)
                }
        }

        return readvalue
    }

}
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

include 'user.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$email= $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 $ris['message']="";

$user = new User();

//procedo con il login
if($user->login($email,$password,"MOBILE")==true){
    $ris['message']="yes";
}


else{
  $ris['message']="no $email";
}

echo json_encode($ris);

?>
```

Comment: Is the problem that your answer is an optional? `readvalue!`

Comment: But if i remove ! I have an error: @AgRizzo

Comment: @AgRizzo so, you need to receive "prova@email.it" without optional?

Comment: @SergeyDi yes !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done something like:

```
if let readvalue = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as? String {
    print(readvalue)
}
```

must print wihtout Optional

Answer (score 0):

Just did this in a playground and it works as expected..

```
import UIKit

let response: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
    "message": "hello world"
]

class MyCoolClass {
    func login() {
        var readvalue = ""

        let jsonData = response as NSDictionary

        readvalue = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String


        debugPrint("the readvalue is: \(readvalue)")

    }
}

let instance = MyCoolClass()
instance.login()
```

This will print: "the readvalue is: hello world"

The code is not very failsafe...

Comment: Could you please let me see how to modify the code above to remove optional?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nil coalescing to make your value non-optional. e.g. `print(readvalue ?? "nil")`. Something better would be reengineer your response handling to properly return a typed value or a specific error.